# How to extend GWT's RPC serialization mechanism?

Tags: serialization, gwt, rpc

I understood, that on GWT's RPCs the parameters are serialized on the client using the ClientSerializationStreamWriter and deserialized on the server using the ServerSerializationStreamReader and the return value on the other hand is serialized on the server using the ServerSerializationStreamWriter and deserialized on the client using the ClientserializationStreamReader.

I'm trying to calculate on the sender's side a checksum or something similar which is based on the serialized parameters (client->server) or return value (server->client) and add it to the serialization stream. On the receiver's side the checksum is re-calculated from the serialized and received parameters or return value (without the additional checksum of course) and compared to the received checksum.

In order to keep the checksum calculation independent of the concrete parameter/return value types, I'd prefer to base the calculation on the serialized values instead of the original types. This would save me additional traversal of the object graphs and thereby from solving another problem: considering all values in the object graph without the possibility to rely on Java's reflection API (which is not available on the client).

I first thought of introducing parameter objects (consisting of the actual parameters of any given RPC) and return value wrappers and then introduce custom field serializers for them. On serialization I could first serialize the parameters/return value, access the serialized values from the *SerializationStreamWriter, calculate the checksum and write the checksum using the same *SerializationStreamReader. However, on the receiver's end it seems I cannot get access to the serialized values without actually reading them with the *SerializationStreamReader as the serialization stream is already tokenized when the first custom field serializer is invoked.

So the question is:

1. is there a hook I've missed? Or
2. is there alternatively an efficient way to serialize an object graph both on the client as well as on the server in the same way (same format) and without the need to implement anything specific to the concrete parameter or return value types?

Comment: How​ about using a servlet filter on server-side, and a custom [`RpcRequestBuilder`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RpcRequestBuilder.html) on client-side?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Thomas (see comment added to question) did answer the question. @Thomas: thanks, that was exactly what I missed in my previous Research.

I can add some details to it.

As proposed by Thomas, on the client side a custom RpcRequestBuilder Needs to be set on the async service Interface:

```
IMyServiceAsync service = GWT.create(IMyService.class);
((ServiceDefTarget)service).setRpcRequestBuilder(new MyCustomRpcRequestBuilder());
```

The custom RpcRequestBuilder needs to override `doSetRequestData` to manipulate the request that is about to be sent and `doSetCallback` to get its hands on the response before it is processed:

```
private final class MyCustomRpcRequestBuilder extends RpcRequestBuilder {
  @Override
  protected void doSetRequestData(RequestBuilder rb, String payload) {
    // do whatever you need to do on the payload, request header, ...
    String checksum = calculateChecksum(payload);
    rb.setHeader(MY_CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME, checksum);
    super.doSetRequestData(rb, payload);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doSetCallback(RequestBuilder rb, final RequestCallback callback) {
    super.doSetCallback(rb, new RequestCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        // do whatever you need to do on the response header, ...
        String receivedChecksum = response.getHeader(MY_CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME);
        if (receivedChecksum.equals(calculateChecksum(response.getText())) {
          callback.onResponseReceived(request, response);
        }
        else {
          callback.onError(request, new InvalidChecksumException(...));
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
        callback.onError(request, exception);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

On the server side a servlet filter can be used. GWT's RPCServletUtils has some useful methods herefore:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {  
  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest)req;
    HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse)resp;

    String receivedChecksum = httpReq.getHeader(MY_CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME);
    String reqPayload = RPCServletUtils.readContentAsGwtRpc(httpReq);
    if (receivedChecksum.equals(calculateChecksum(reqPayload)) {
      final ServletInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayServletInputStream(reqPayload.getBytes(RPCServletUtils.CHARSET_UTF8));
      HttpServletRequestWrapper reqWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpReq) {
        @Override
        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
          return inputStream;
        }
      };
      final CachingServletOutputStream outputStream = new CachingServletOutputStream();
      HttpServletResponseWrapper respWrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(httpResp) {
        @Override
        public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
          return outputStream;
        }
      };

      filterChain.doFilter(reqWrapper, respWrapper);

      // possibly you also need to handle gzipped payload
      String respPayload = new String(outputStream.getCachedDataAsBytes(), RPCServletUtils.CHARSET_UTF8);
      String checksum = calculateChecksum(respPayload);
      httpResp.setHeader(MY_CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME, checksum);
      httpResp.getOutputStream().write(outputStream.getCachedDataAsBytes());
    } else {
      httpResp.setContentType("text/plain");
      httpResp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
      httpResp.getOutputStream().write("Invalid checksum".getBytes(RPCServletUtils.CHARSET_UTF8));
    }
  }

  static class ByteArrayServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {
    private final InputStream delegate;

    ByteArrayServletInputStream(byte[] data) throws IOException, ServletException {
      delegate = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
      return delegate.read();
    }
  }

  static class CachingServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream cache;

    CachingServletOutputStream() {
      this.cache = new  ByteArrayOutputStream(4096);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
      cache.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
      cache.flush();
    }

    byte[] getCachedDataAsBytes() {
      return cache.toByteArray();
    }
  }
}
```